# The states is updating but not rendering

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-hooks, leaflet, react-leaflet

When I wanna click recover or deaths I want to change circle color. When I was consoled state value updated but circles color didn't change. Here are codes and pictures. I tried everything I know but didnt work. Why my state doesnt recognize new value as a new value and not trigger refresh? Any help?

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmvaV.png)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import "./App.css";
    import {
      MenuItem,
      FormControl,
      Select,
      Card,
      CardContent,
    } from "@material-ui/core";
    import InfoBox from "../src/InfoBox/InfoBox";
    import LineGraph from "../src/LineGraph/LineGraph";
    import Table from "../src/Table/Table";
    import { sortData, prettyPrintStat } from "./util";
    import numeral from "numeral";
    import CovidMap from "../src/Map/CovidMap";
    import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
    
    const App = () => {
      const [country, setInputCountry] = useState("worldwide");
      const [countryInfo, setCountryInfo] = useState({});
      const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
      const [mapCountries, setMapCountries] = useState([]);
      const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
      const [casesType, setCasesType] = useState("cases");
      const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState([34, -40]);
      const [mapZoom, setMapZoom] = useState(3);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all")
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setCountryInfo(data);
          });
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const getCountriesData = async () => {
          fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
              const countries = data.map((country) => ({
                name: country.country,
                value: country.countryInfo.iso2,
              }));
              let sortedData = sortData(data);
              setCountries(countries);
              setMapCountries(data);
              setTableData(sortedData);
            });
        };
    
        getCountriesData();
      }, []);
    
      console.log(casesType);
    
      const onCountryChange = async (e) => {
        const countryCode = e.target.value;
    
        const url =
          countryCode === "worldwide"
            ? "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all"
            : `https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/${countryCode}`;
        await fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setInputCountry(countryCode);
            setCountryInfo(data);
            setMapCenter([data.countryInfo.lat, data.countryInfo.long]);
            setMapZoom(4);
          });
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="app">
          <div className="left">
            <div className="header">
              <h1>Caner Demir COVID Tracker</h1>
              <FormControl className="dropdown">
                <Select
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={country}
                  onChange={onCountryChange}
                >
                  <MenuItem value="worldwide">Worldwide</MenuItem>
                  {countries.map((country) => (
                    <MenuItem value={country.value}>{country.name}</MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </div>
            <div className="stats">
              <InfoBox
                onClick={(e) => setCasesType("cases")}
                title="Coronavirus Cases"
                isRed
                active={casesType === "cases"}
                cases={prettyPrintStat(countryInfo.todayCases)}
                total={numeral(countryInfo.cases).format("0.0a")}
              />
              <InfoBox
                onClick={(e) => setCasesType("recovered")}
                title="Recovered"
                active={casesType === "recovered"}
                cases={prettyPrintStat(countryInfo.todayRecovered)}
                total={numeral(countryInfo.recovered).format("0.0a")}
              />
              <InfoBox
                onClick={(e) => setCasesType("deaths")}
                title="Deaths"
                isRed
                active={casesType === "deaths"}
                cases={prettyPrintStat(countryInfo.todayDeaths)}
                total={numeral(countryInfo.deaths).format("0.0a")}
              />
            </div>
            <CovidMap
              countries={mapCountries}
              casesType={casesType}
              center={mapCenter}
              zoom={mapZoom}
              showDataOnMap
            />
          </div>
          <Card className="right">
            <CardContent>
              <div className="information">
                <h3>Live Cases by Country</h3>
                <Table countries={tableData} />
                <h3>Worldwide new {casesType}</h3>
                <LineGraph className="graph" casesType={casesType} />
              </div>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```

/**/

```
   import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import "./Map.css";
import numeral from "numeral";
import { Circle, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

export default function CovidMap({ countries, casesType, center, zoom }) {
  const casesTypeColors = {
    cases: {
      hex: "#CC1034",
      multiplier: 120,
    },
    recovered: {
      hex: "#7DD71D",
      multiplier: 100,
    },
    deaths: {
      hex: "#FB4443",
      multiplier: 300,
    },
  };
  const showDataOnMap = (data, casesType) =>
    data.map((country) => (
      <Circle
        center={[country.countryInfo.lat, country.countryInfo.long]}
        color={casesTypeColors[casesType].hex}
        fillColor={casesTypeColors[casesType].hex}
        fillOpacity={0.4}
        radius={
          Math.sqrt(country[casesType]) * casesTypeColors[casesType].multiplier
        }
      >
        <Popup>
          <div className="info-container">
            <div
              className="info-flag"
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${country.countryInfo.flag})` }}
            ></div>
            <div className="info-name">{country.country}</div>
            <div className="info-confirmed">
              Cases: {numeral(country.cases).format("0,0")}
            </div>
            <div className="info-recovered">
              Recovered: {numeral(country.recovered).format("0,0")}
            </div>
            <div className="info-deaths">
              Deaths: {numeral(country.deaths).format("0,0")}
            </div>
          </div>
        </Popup>
      </Circle>
    ));

  return (
    <div className="map">
      <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom}>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
        {showDataOnMap(countries, casesType)}
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: After re-reading your implementation, I couldn't see what might be causing the problem, so I created a [minimum reproducible example in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-platform-9uk1r1?file=/src/App.js) which seems to be working just fine. I would recommend adding more logging within the CovidMap component to double check that the updated value is reaching the child element properly and not being interrupted with a useEffect or race condition not visible in the code you posted so far.

Comment: Hey. When I console casesTypeColors[casesType].hex in the Map component I get the hex code. In other words, it takes both state and gives the correct hex code according to the click. But the color does not change.

Comment: That feedback helped me realize what the problem is. I added it as an answer below. I hope it works out for you!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [circle Leaflet documentation](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/), the `color`, `fillColor`, and `fillOpacity` properties should be passed as an object in `pathOptions`, not at the root level of the element.

Changing the `<Circle />` component props to the following should fix your problem:

```js
<Circle
  center={[country.countryInfo.lat, country.countryInfo.long]}
  pathOptions={{
    color: casesTypeColors[casesType].hex,
    fillColor: casesTypeColors[casesType].hex,
    fillOpacity: 0.4
  }}
  radius={
     Math.sqrt(country[casesType]) * casesTypeColors[casesType].multiplier
  }
>
```

Comment: Heeeyy. Thank you so much. Please excuse me for making you tired because of my carelessness. Ty so much again ^^